# How to deal with changing column names

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In my case, the data table has columns for each week and month, cumulatively for 3 months.
Refer image [Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC4xY.jpg)
As I will be analyzing the data, the week and month will be dynamically changes.
As I have created various custom columns and measures in this data table based on the source columns, whenever am uploading the data files, the column reference changes and am forced to create all those measures once again.

Am expecting to keep my data model same, irrespective of the column name changes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to know how to deal with changing column headings. There are a bunch of resources out there showing you how to do it, for example [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBJr0sAc-m4).

I am using this technique in a bunch of queries where I have to take into account that the user producing the table may overwrite the header, which would cause all subsequent query steps to "bomb".

Since you haven't provided sample data, I'm using my own. The goal is to take whatever is in the first cell of the column and swap it out for "UPC". Yes, that will overwrite the first entry, but it's the only way I could get it to work.

**Example 1**:

```
+-----------+
| 145782456 |
| 784631578 |
|   2457819 |
|  00215873 |
| 030485971 |
+-----------+
```

***STEP 1*** - enter a custom formula into the formula bar of the Power Query editor as follows:

```
List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Navigation), each ((Text.Contains(_, "0") or Text.Contains(_, "1") or Text.Contains(_, "2") or Text.Contains(_, "3") or Text.Contains(_, "4") or Text.Contains(_, "5") or Text.Contains(_, "6") or Text.Contains(_, "7") or Text.Contains(_, "8") or Text.Contains(_, "9"))) or Text.Contains(_,"UPC"))
```

Call/rename the step `"OldNames"` or something that suits you better.

***STEP 2*** - enter a list of new names you want to swap the old ones out for as a list into the formula bar of the Power Query editor. Here, I'm just entering one term, as all I want is the word "UPC":

```
{"UPC"}
```

Call/rename this step `"NewNames"` or whatever you'd like. If you have more than one term, enter them in quotes like the first one, separated by commas.

***STEP 3*** - swap out the old names for the new ones:

```
List.Zip({OldNames,NewNames})
```

Call/rename this step `"Renamed"`.

***STEP 4*** - rename the columns:

```
Table.RenameColumns(Navigation,Renamed)
```

The previews should now show you the new column names at the top. All other steps should come after the dynamic renaming.

Here is the full M code (I'm doing a few other things here, and the path to the file points to SharePoint:

```
let
  Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("[FULL SHAREPOINT PATH TO FILE"), null, true),
  Navigation = Source{[Item = "Table1", Kind = "Table"]}[Data],
  OldNames = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Navigation), each ((Text.Contains(_, "0") or Text.Contains(_, "1") or Text.Contains(_, "2") or Text.Contains(_, "3") or Text.Contains(_, "4") or Text.Contains(_, "5") or Text.Contains(_, "6") or Text.Contains(_, "7") or Text.Contains(_, "8") or Text.Contains(_, "9"))) or Text.Contains(_,"UPC")),
  NewNames = {"UPC"},
  Renamed = List.Zip({OldNames,NewNames}),
  Custom = Table.RenameColumns(Navigation,Renamed),
  #"Removed duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Custom, {"UPC"}),
  #"Removed blank rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed duplicates", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
  #"Transform columns" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed blank rows", {{"UPC", type text}}),
  #"Replace errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Transform columns", {{"UPC", null}})
in
  #"Replace errors"
```

This is the output:

```
+-----------+
|    UPC    |
+-----------+
| 784631578 |
|   2457819 |
|  00215873 |
| 030485971 |
+-----------+
```

**Example 2**: I am using the same technique for a huge table where I have to unpivot somewhat arbitrary date columns. I'm not going to go into as much detail with this one, but here is the M code, which seemingly does nothing, but under the hood it will parse any date columns into a list, like above, then using that list to name the columns again, so I don't have to deal with these date columns changing all the time.

```
let
  Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("[FULL SHAREPOINT PATH TO FILE]"), null, true),
  Navigation = Source{[Item = "Sheet1", Kind = "Sheet"]}[Data],
  Headers = Table.PromoteHeaders(Navigation, [PromoteAllScalars = true]),
  ColumnNames = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Headers), each (Text.Contains(_, "/"))),
  DynamicNames = ColumnNames,
  Renamed = List.Zip({ColumnNames,DynamicNames}),
  DynamicallyRename = Table.RenameColumns(Headers,Renamed),
  #"Unpivoted columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(DynamicallyRename, {"SKU", "Item Description", "Total On Order"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
  #"Replaced value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted columns", "Qty Due", "", Replacer.ReplaceText, {"Attribute"}),
  #"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced value", {{"Attribute", type date}, {"Value", Int64.Type}, {"Total On Order", Int64.Type}, {"Item Description", type text}, {"SKU", type text}}),
  #"Renamed columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed column type", {{"Attribute", "Date Expected"}, {"Value", "QOO"}})
in
  #"Renamed columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel style cross-tables will bring you nowhere in PowerBI. Your first step after importing the data should be unpivoting the weekdate columns.

see [Unpivot Columns (PowerQuery)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098)