# Power Query Table.ExpandColumns takes long time

Tags: powerquery

Hello all and thank you for reading,

I have a small problem that is getting me mad :
In Power Query, I've just joined two tables with the code that follow :

```
= Table.NestedJoin(#"Add YEAR", {"ID_LOT_RECETTE"}, TARGET, {"CODE_RECETTE"}, "TARGET", JoinKind.LeftOuter)
```

The hard thing here is that I want to expand the table, but as the number and name of the columns of the joined table may change, I do not want to hard code all the names of the columns that I want to expand.

[Here the table that I've just merged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TIZa.png)

To avoid this hard coding, I created a list with the names of all the columns that exist in the joined table.

```
= List.Union(List.Transform(#"Merge TARGET"[TARGET], each Table.ColumnNames(_)))
```

Problem is that as the table has many columns, when I applied the Table.ExpandTableColumn using the list, the time to run this step is very big (> 4 minutes)

```
= Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merge TARGET", "TARGET", List_TARGETS, List_TARGETS_renamed)
```

Could someone help me with this big issue ?

THANK YOU

I expect to be able to have a query that will do the job in a short time.

Comment: I just answered a similar question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75517529/how-to-deal-with-changing-column-names/75521023#75521023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75517529/how-to-deal-with-changing-column-names/75521023#75521023)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** never mind.  Question changed after posted answer

See if this helps

In powerquery this combines all the XLSX files in a folder, regardless of tab and column names

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: Thank you very match for your answer horseride, I confirm this code works but I edited my post as I my problem was not what I initilly posted.

Comment: Oh.  Well I guess I answered a question that no longer exists. Anyway, there is no faster way to expand

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. In any case the code you pasted works very well, but gives me the problem of being really slow when the List that you use for Table.ExpandTableColumn has many items.

Comment: Having less columns is the only way to speed it up. Or perhaps try in PowerBI instead of powerquery, or on a better horse-powered machine.  there is no faster operational way to expand. Depending on the leading steps, you could try Table.Buffer() around the source table if referenced multiple times

Comment: Ok, even if there's no other way to do it, I needed to know it. I will have a look at Table.Buffer(). Thank you for your time and patience horoseride

Answer (score 0):

Table.ExpandTableColumn appears to execute very slowly where the list of column names is not hard coded.

Avoiding use of Table.ExpandTableColumn is quicker in my scripts. Modifying horseyride's code above:

```
let
  Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
  #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
  #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name","Content"}),
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
  #"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
  #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),

  Data_Tables_Lst = List.Transform(Table.ToRecords(#"Removed Columns"), each [Data] ),
  #"Expanded Data" = Table.Combine(Data_Tables_Lst)

in
  #"Expanded Data"
```